# Hyperledger Iroha - Use Case Scenarios

Tags: hyperledger, hyperledger-iroha

I find Iroha to be a way more simple way to implement a blockchain network compared to the nightmare of a learning curve Fabric is.

My question is: I have to build a POC that includes a main company transferring monthly financial documents to its clients through a blockchain (not my idea, do not ask me why). I know I can do that with Iroha, but I need to understand if that's the correct application to the platform. If so, what should be the correct approach? **Should I create one asset for each type of document? Or maybe one asset for each document the company sends?**

Could someone help me with that?

Answer (score 2):

There are a few ways to do this, but if I were to program this myself, I would most likely have each client register an account on the blockchain and then put the hash of each document in the client's AccountDetail storage, by calling setAccountDetail (https://iroha.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/commands.html#set-account-detail).

Then the documents themselves could be transferred outside of the blockchain, directly to the client in an encrypted form.

Comment: Thanks man, but I think if I use this way It would not make sense to use Iroha for that.